# How can I print in a PDF format from flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I created an app for generating invoices and want to print the invoice from the printing button in the application, I am new to flutter and have no idea how to do that.I have tried to find something regarding this on the internet but wasnt able to find one, all the examples are of receipt from a thermal printer. I want it for android app only. My code is in dart only. I want it to print like a pdf document

Comment: Are you asking how to create a PDF file, how to print a PDF file to a physical printer, or something else?

Comment: yes how to create a PDF document within the application and print it without saving the document in files of the device.

Comment: Is there any way to print pdf in thermal printer?